# How can I get javascript value in another js file

Tags: javascript

How can I get `result.id` value into another `js`. I printed in console but I unable get into another `js`.

```
       app.helpers.renderUsers = function() {
                   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                       var tpl = _.template( $('#user_tpl').html() ),
                           usersHTML = '',
                           users = [];
                    console.log("INSIDE login --> STARTS");
                       QB.users.get({'login': ["dev_visirx000534"]}, function(err, result){
                           if (err) {
                             console.log("INSIDE login --> error");
                               reject(err);
                           } else {
                               _.each(result.items, function(item) {
                                 console.log("INSIDE login --> success");
                                   users.push(item.user);
                                    console.log(app.caller.id);
                                   if( item.user.id !== app.caller.id ) {
                                       usersHTML += tpl(item.user);
                                   }
                               });
                               console.log("Patient QB Id:------->"+result.id) //      how to get value in another js       



                           }
                       });
                   });
               };
```

Comment: Pass it to a function into *`another.js`*

Comment: create global variable var new_var;  and assign the value to global variable new_var=result.id; and now  get it into anther file

Comment: Like JYoThl says you could use a global var, but global var's are best avoided, it's usually best if you have some sort of module bundler, like webpack, you can then pass into functions like Adam Azad said.

Comment: i passed the function like this but i unable get the value" return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {});"

Comment: Grammatical mistakes and code highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Return resolve value like

```
 return Deferred.Promise.resolve(result.id);
```

and in recievier side call

```
return app.helpers.renderUsers().then(function(id) {
  alert(id);   
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: i am getting this error :"Uncaught ReferenceError: Deferred is not defined"